# set value in BaseFieldControl or RichTextField

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want programmatical set value in my own field type. So I override method FieldRenderingControl (this is call when click into element in sharepoint list).

my code:

```
 public override Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseFieldControl FieldRenderingControl
        {
            get
            {
                BaseFieldControl fakeFieldControl = base.FieldRenderingControl;

                RichTextField rtf = new RichTextField();
                rtf.ID = "MultilineRichText";
                rtf.ListId = fakeFieldControl.ListId;// list.ID;
                rtf.ItemId = fakeFieldControl.ItemId;// item.ID;
                rtf.FieldName = "MultilineRichText";
                rtf.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;
                rtf.Text = "test rich text";
                rtf.Value = "test rich text value";

                rtf.ItemFieldValue = "item field value";
                rtf.ListItemFieldValue = "list item field value";



                return rtf;
```

the result: contol mode is always in display mode, that work fine. But the column value is always empty.

Any help? I do not have any idea!

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you have to set the value BEFORE setting the ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display.

Edit: I just saw that's an old post... hope you had find an answer :)